# Why do I have 4 Sets of Icons

Tags: kde, gentoo, nautilus, trash

Since a picture speaks 1,000 words:

[image: Nautilus With 4 Cans]

Why is this happening in KDE 4.14.3.  The Gentoo Stable package of `kde-base/kde-meta`

I've emptied my user's Trash Can, but how can I determine why I have 4 Sets of the default Icons...

---

As per comment's, the following XML file is loaded:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE xbel>
<xbel xmlns:bookmark="http://www.freedesktop.org/standards/desktop-bookmarks" xmlns:mime="http://www.freedesktop.org/standards/shared-mime-info" xmlns:kdepriv="http://www.kde.org/kdepriv">
 <bookmark href="file:///home/myUser">
  <title>Home</title>
  <info>
   <metadata owner="http://freedesktop.org">
    <bookmark:icon name="user-home"/>
   </metadata>
   <metadata owner="http://www.kde.org">
    <ID>1434256040/0</ID>
    <isSystemItem>true</isSystemItem>
   </metadata>
  </info>
 </bookmark>
 <bookmark href="remote:/">
  <title>Network</title>
  <info>
   <metadata owner="http://freedesktop.org">
    <bookmark:icon name="network-workgroup"/>
   </metadata>
   <metadata owner="http://www.kde.org">
    <ID>1434256040/1</ID>
    <isSystemItem>true</isSystemItem>
   </metadata>
  </info>
 </bookmark>
 <bookmark href="file:///">
  <title>Root</title>
  <info>
   <metadata owner="http://freedesktop.org">
    <bookmark:icon name="folder-red"/>
   </metadata>
   <metadata owner="http://www.kde.org">
    <ID>1434256040/2</ID>
    <isSystemItem>true</isSystemItem>
   </metadata>
  </info>
 </bookmark>
 <bookmark href="trash:/">
  <title>Trash</title>
  <info>
   <metadata owner="http://freedesktop.org">
    <bookmark:icon name="user-trash"/>
   </metadata>
   <metadata owner="http://www.kde.org">
    <ID>1434256040/3</ID>
    <isSystemItem>true</isSystemItem>
   </metadata>
  </info>
 </bookmark>
</xbel>
```

I don't see any errors at first glance so I'm still stumped...

Comment: Well, you know, 1 trash can in the kitchen, 1 trash can in the bathroom, and so on :-)

Comment: @Celada HA/LOL, but that isn't exactly the problem...

Comment: Try to get a fifth set of icons. When you reached your goal, you'll probably know why you had 4 before. ;)

Comment: Check the contents of `~/.local/share/user-places.xbel`, if you find duplicate entries, remove them.

Comment: @Mr.Yetti - Thank you!!, now at least I know where it's stored.  I was expecting 4 Entries, but no luck... I've posted the file in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my Issue.  Somehow, I created a shortcut, and 2 copies.  I removed the shortcut, and both copies.  Issue is fixed.